# Solana Bigtable Replication

Tags: node, bigtable

I'm following [these instructions](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-bigtable#import-solana%27s-bigtable-instance) for setting up a warehouse node. The key step is cloning the blockchain data directly through GCP. For that to happen, either joe@solana.com or axl@solana.com must approve my service account, but they're not answering my emails. Is there an alternative way to go around this? Are there are other warehouse nodes operators I could get in contact with?